# Unknown column even though the column exists

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I get an error, `Unknown column 'events.event_id' in 'field list'` even though my table clearly has the column, as shown in the attached screenshot:

[image]

My SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT
   `events`.`event_id`,
   `events`.`realm`,
   `events`.`starts`,
   `events`.`ends`,
   `general_data`.`id`,
   `general_data`.`nick`
FROM `events`
JEFT JOIN
   `general_data` ON `events`.`owner`=`general_data`.`id`
WHERE
   `instance`=1 AND
   `zone`=1 AND
   (`realm`='foo' OR `crossrealm`=1)
ORDER BY
   `events`.`starts`,`events`.`realm` ASC
LIMIT 0,50
```

Could anyone please offer some insight to what migh tbe causing this problem?

Comment: That's wacky.  Can you post the output of 'show create table events'?

Comment: No problem with others fields? I mean, if you remove event_id, is it works?

Comment: @sdespont I've just tested this and yes, the same happens to other fields, too.

Comment: `events` could be a reserved table name.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try renaming it and see how that goes.

Comment: And no, it didn't help.

Comment: Yeah, I tried a SQL fiddle and it works with your table name. Sorry to ask, but are you sure that you are using the right DB?

Comment: Definitely, I've even included `USE \`this_database\`;` in the query to be sure.

Comment: Hard to help you without your tables creation code.

Comment: I am unsure how to check it, would gladly provide it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JEFT JOIN

Did you type it wrong or? It should be LEFT JOIN i guess

Comment: This must be the most embarrassing error I've ever encountered, especially after it's taken me two hours to figure out the solution. Too bad I haven't seen your answer sooner...